# Why I can't get function reference by JSContext in Swift when using Arrow function

Tags: javascript, swift, javascriptcore

I am trying to get a JavaScript function reference in Swift and execute it.

Initially,  I used [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#arrow_functions) in JS side, my JavaScript function is like this.

```js
const invokeCallback = (cbID, args) => {   
    // do some stuff
}
```

And in the Swift side, i use `objectForKeyedSubscript` in `JSContent` to get the property `invokeCallback` in the context’s global object.

```swift
    context?.evaluateScript(jsCodeContent)
    let invoke: JSValue? = context?.objectForKeyedSubscript("invokeCallback")
    
    guard let invokeCallback = invoke else { return }
    guard !invokeCallback.isUndefined else { return }
        
    invokeCallback.call(withArguments: [cbId, args])
```

But I can't it turns out the result is `undefined`.

```
Printing description of invoke:
▿ Optional<JSValue>
  - some : undefined
```

Then, I tried this syntax to define the `function`.

```
function invokeCallback(cbID, args) {
}
```

I can retrieve the function in Swift side now

```
Printing description of invokeCallback:
function invokeCallback(cbID, args) {
   // ....
}
```

Do someone know why the first case doesn't work while the second one work? Kindlyshare this knowledge to me? thanks

Ref:

- [1 javascriptcore](https://nshipster.com/javascriptcore/)
- [2 javascriptcore-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1227-javascriptcore-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started#toc-anchor-009)

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't the arrow function, but the way you declare your function.

Functions declared with a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) that are in the global context, become part of the global object.

Variables that are declared with `var` in the global context also become part of the global object. In that case it doesn't matter whether you assign an (arrow) function expression or any other value.

Variables declared with `const` in the global context [*do not* become part of the global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#description).

Because your arrow function is assigned to a variable that is declared with `const`, it is not part of the global object and so you cannot find it. If you want your function to become part of the global object, you should either use a function declaration, declare your variable with `var`, or assign it directly to the global object.

```
globalThis.invokeCallback = () => {...};
```

It is also worth noting that arrow functions and regular function expression ([not to be confused with function declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)) [are not always interchangeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable).